# Filter all specified tags with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, join

Let's say I have the following tables:

```
GmTag
TagId: integer
Tag: string

GmProTab
ProId: integer
ProDes: string

GmProTag
ProTagId: integer
ProId: integer
TagId: integer
```

With SqlServer I write:

```
    SELECT p.*
  FROM GmProTab p
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                 FROM GmProTag tg
                 JOIN GmTag t ON t.TagId = tg.TagId
                WHERE t.tag IN ('Brinco', 'Argola')
                  AND tg.ProId = p.ProId
             GROUP BY tg.ProId
               HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.Tag) = 2)
```

How can I code it in EF core?

Comment: one approach would be - You would end up writing a linq query in c#, for the respective entities from EF. you may create a data repo class that would return this linq query result connecting with EF.core to your desired calling method/class.

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/using-linq) to rewrite the query after you get your [database connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/configuring/connection-strings) and everything set up for your [DBContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/working-with-dbcontext), assuming you go that route.

It can take some time to get all of this set up, but if you follow the EF docs, you should be able to see it all come together. First get your DB to at least connect, then do some simple queries against the DBSet. After that, you should be all set to actually write the query.

It is common to leverage the repository pattern. You'll also have to write the Entity classes for your tables if you are doing Code-First. If you are using the .edmx/database first approach, you will still need to make sure it generates the proper Entity classes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my (more or less) literal translation of your SQL:

```
var ans = from p in GmProTab
          where (from tg in GmProTag
                 join t in GmTag on tg.TagId equals t.TagId
                 where new[] { "Brinco", "Argola" }.Contains(t.Tag) && tg.ProId == p.ProId
                 group t by tg.ProId
                 ).Any(t_g => t_g.Select(t => t.Tag).Distinct().Count() == 2)
          select p;
```

And here is my re-working to use `join` instead of a sub-query (untested):

```
var ans2 = from p in GmProTab
           join tg in GmProTag on p.ProId equals tg.ProId
           join t in GmTag on tg.TagId equals t.TagId
           group t by p into t_g
           where t_g.Any(t2 => t2.Tag == "Brinco") && t_g.Any(t2 => t2.Tag == "Argola")
           select t_g.Key;
```